# Eigenvalues of Bose-Hubbard model

Tags: solid-state-physics

I want to see eigenvalue spectrum of Bose-Hubbard Hamiltonian. Can anyone send me the algorithm to write Bose-Hubbard Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1):

https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.4006
you can see the algorithm [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.4006)